# how to get dictionary and thesaurus completion

Tags: autocompletion

`<C-x><C-K>` allows for dictionary completion, and `<C-x><C-T>` for thesaurus completion.

How can I get both completions at once?

Ideally, is there a way I can add the thesaurus results to the bottom of the dictionary results?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `'complete'` to `kspell,s`, then use `CTRL-N` instead of the mappings you referred to. See `:h compl-generic` and `:h 'complete'` for details